# iOS 11 beta 5, MKGeodesicPolyline doesn't scale correctly when zooming in/out

Tags: ios, mkmapview, xcode9-beta, mkpolyline

I have some code that draws the polyline on the map. It seems like when I am running it on iOS 11 beta 5, the line doesn't scale correctly if I zoom in and out of the map. Here are the screen shots:

Sometimes I get the correct result.
[image]
Sometimes the polyline doesn't scale correctly initially after creating the map or after zooming in and out of the map.
[image] 
Here is how I add the polyline to the map:

```
let polyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)  
map.add(polyline)
```

Here is how I create the renderer:

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer? {  
        if overlay is MKPolyline {  
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)  
            renderer.strokeColor = color      
            renderer.lineWidth = 3  
            renderer.lineJoin = .round  
            renderer.lineCap = .round  

            return renderer  
        }  

        return nil  
    }
```

The same code runs fine on iOS 10. On iOS 11, the issue is more prominent on the device than simulator. Appreciate it if someone can help me resolve this.

Comment: This seems like a bug but one can never be sure. File a radar.

Comment: Beta 6 seems to fix it.